# Cannot connect AWS with SAP HANA

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, hana

We are trying to connect SAP HANA with AWS Glue. We find that documentation is out of date, so it's not a good guide.

We keep finding this error when we (try to) execute a job

[image]

and

[image]

Also, it doesn't let us test the connection
[image]

Does anyone have a nice updated documentation or any help to connect SAP HANA with AWS?

Also, our SAP HANA server is not in AWS, we are trying to connect to the external provider.